# How to loop over query data and insert in structure?

Tags: struct, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11

I have query data that should be inserted in the structure. While looping over data each value should be assigned to matching column. Here is example of query data:

```
    REC_ID  NAME    STATUS      TYPE    YEAR
1   01      PARIS   Approved    1       2019
2   06      AUSTIN  Inactive    3       2017
3   48      LONDON  Approved    2       2018
4   43      ROME    Inactive    5       2019
5   61      DUBLIN  Inactive    4       2019
```

This data should be organized to look like this:

```
1
  REC_ID  01
  NAME    PARIS
  STATUS  Approved
  TYPE    1
  YEAR    2019
2
  REC_ID  06
  NAME    AUSTIN
  STATUS  Inactive
  TYPE    3
  YEAR    2017
3
  REC_ID  48
  NAME    LONDON
  STATUS  Approved
  TYPE    2
  YEAR    2018
4
  REC_ID  43
  NAME    ROME
  STATUS  Inactive
  TYPE    5
  YEAR    2019
5
  REC_ID  61
  NAME    DUBLIN
  STATUS  Inactive
  TYPE    4
  YEAR    2019
```

I tried to get desired data format with this function:

```
function formatData(qryData) {
    local.fnResult = structNew();
    local.fnData = structNew();

    if(qryData.recordcount){
        for(row in qryData) {
            for(column in qryData.columnList) {
                local.strRec = structNew();
                structInsert(strRec, column, row[column]);
                local.fnData[qryData.currentrow] = strRec;
            }
        }
    }

    writeDump(fnData);
}
```

Here is how my result looks:

```
1
  REC_ID  01
2
  REC_ID  06
3
  REC_ID  48
4
  REC_ID  43
5
  REC_ID  61
```

I use ColdFusion 11 cfscript syntax. If anyone can help me solve this problem please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you reorganizing a query result? Is this for display? If so, this should be handled with your front-end code.

Comment: Upon closer look, It seems you want a struct with numbered keys. That seems like an unusual approach. Is there a reason to not use an array?

Comment: @JamesAMohler I prefer working with structs and having unique key for each record. Is there any major difference in using array?

Comment: @Shawn Yes, this is used for display purpose. I organize the query data with CF and then output in JS variable. Do you have better way of doing that?

Comment: @espresso_coffee. The advantages are 1) Arrays are lighter weight than structs 2) structs inherently are strings which are slower to compare than numbers 3) arrays are faster. I can demonstrate the faster with this link https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=ac88b0f5-48fd-4c55-a8ad-86be2e83aefb/3552f8ed-c46f-4f2e-8416-acff12c0877b/8d9cc3e4-a90d-4ffb-8b39-ba7dfc2317a7.cfm 4) I have had to structs with numbers as key only once in 20+ years. It was because he numbers were large and somewhat random. If I would have used an array, I will be very empty

Comment: It seems you may be making CF do extra work. How are you ultimately using this data?

Comment: @Shawn On page load I need to return record count from the query. That is the only information that will be displayed at that point. While I'm loading the data for record count I want to load the query in javascript variable. Then when user needs to access that query data I can simply pull that with javascript. Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you expecting those results to be ordered in any way?

Comment: Yes, they should be ordered by recid.

Comment: @JamesAMohler I forgot the mention the other reason why I would use struct with key method is mainly because the situation where I need to pull specific record from the object. In that case I can simply pass the key in the structure and get the data.

Comment: Arrays are identical. If you have an array and you need item x, one can use `myArray[x]`

Comment: @JamesAMohler Can I for example set x to be any random unique number (integer type) in that case?

Comment: It can be set to any random number. It does not have to be completely filled in. Having said that, I have only used that approach maybe 1% of the time and I heavily comment it. Having said all this, it might be useful to put on SO, of how you are using structs with numbered keys. I know I am suggesting quite a different approach, it would be good to know how different the code would be.

Comment: Are you passing the query results to the page, or is the query run at the same time as the page? What is the basic workflow of this page. I'm kinda just guessing at how your page works. How are you outputting the variables?

Comment: @Shawn This is a welcome page in the system (very old system). When user first login they get to this page. At that time I have to pull number of records from the query and display them on the page for the user (yes, query is run on page load). Once that's complete user is able to click on the link that is displaying number of records. At this point I need to display the query data to the user. My idea is to run query on page load, then store data in JS variable. The data should be already organized at that point only thing I need to do is call JS function that will display data to the user.

Comment: I don't know what your display code looks like, but you can pass JSON data through regular HTML data- attributes. Those attributes can be populated directly from your ColdFusion query. Without knowing the flow of this system, I think this does what you're looking for.  CREATING A NEW ARRAY OF DATA: https://trycf.com/gist/7821ba728fdd91e0ea014b83bc7895e5/acf11?theme=monokai  JUST USING THE CF QUERY OBJECT: https://trycf.com/gist/bca9e78fbfc090f63a148ec3ddafecb7/acf11?theme=monokai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue with your column list loop, you are creating a new structure for each column and that get reset in the next loop.

This loop should be changed

```
for(column in qryData.columnList) {
    local.strRec = structNew();
    structInsert(strRec, column, row[column]);
    local.fnData[qryData.currentrow] = strRec;
}
```

to look like

```
local.strRec = structNew();
for(column in qryData.columnList) {
    structInsert(strRec, column, row[column]);
}
local.fnData[qryData.currentrow] = strRec;
```

Comment: So basically define the structure outside of the loop that iterates over the columns and then append the record.

Comment: Yup, that is basically it.

Answer (score 3):

@espresso_coffee, Here I've go through your problem. I hope you need to create a structure with key as row count and each key value should be in a structure format. Here I've provide some sample code for with my query. I hope it's useful to you.

```
<cfquery name="readStudent" datasource="student">
    select * from  user
</cfquery>
```

In my user table having 6 records with firstname, lastName & id. Here I've loop over the query and convert it in to structure key values. I've used script syntax because your code having script style. :)

```
<cfscript>
    myStr = {};
    for (row in readStudent) { 
        structInsert(myStr, #readStudent.currentrow#, row);
    }
    writeDump(myStr);
</cfscript>
```

Here I've create my first structure name as myStr, and loop over query data and insert a structure value for key with current row that is **readStudent.currentRow** and value is in **row** . The row having firstname,lastname & id as structure key & it's value.

**FYR :** I've attached my sample query and converted to  structure value. Correct me if I'm wrong understood your problem

[image]

I hope it's helpful to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, it looks like you could just

```
array function formatData(qryData) {
   return DeserializeJSON(SerializeJSON(arguments.qryData, "struct"));
}
```

[Runnable example on trycf.com](https://trycf.com/gist/5181e9c6168b1aecdf47ba260ac3718e/acf11?theme=monokai)

**Result:**

[image: Screenshot of result]

**Alternative**

```
array function formatData(qryData) {
   var result = [];

   for (var row in qryData) {
       result.append(row);
   }       

   return result;
}
```

Comment: I do not think that "struct" is supported in serializeJSON() in CF11.

Comment: Apparently [it is](https://trycf.com/gist/bbb44c1a756142ef985504a738b60553/acf11?theme=monokai), albeit poorly documented. @JamesAMohler - Nice. Learn something new every day....

Comment: @JamesAMohler - To help convince skeptics (like myself), I added a gist and image of the results ;-). Feel free to modify or roll it back if you don't like the changes.